# Why does std::queue not have operator[]?

Tags: c++, queue, subscript-operator

The `std::queue` is implemented with a deque by default. `std::deque` has the subscript operator, `operator[]`, and is probably implemented with arrays. So why doesn't `std::queue` have `operator[]`?

I realize you could have a queue with a list as the underlying container. (`std::queue<int, std::list<int>>`.) But even if that would make the subscript operator slow, is that really a good reason not to include it? That's the only reason I can think of that it is not included.

Comment: If you need operator[], why would you use a queue?

Comment: Well, the real reason is that it was part of an assignment some other students had when I was lab tutor this past year. They were supposed to use a queue specifically, but it would have been a lot easier if they could peek at a few elements after the front. Really an artificial reason. :P In real life I'd just use a deque.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the definition of queue doesn't support such interface. Queue is a FIFO data structure which means First In First Out. Queue supports *enqueue* and *dequeue*  operations.

Imagine of queue as pipe : you insert data into one end and from the other end you take it out - one by one. Inserting data is called enqueue and taking them out is called dequeue. The C++ standard library has [`std::queue`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/queue.html) which defines both these operations: `push()` is the name of enqueue operation, and dequeue operation has been splitted into two steps namely `front()` followed by `pop()`. The rationale why dequeue has been split into two steps is to give *strong exception guarantee*<sup>1</sup>.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29) explains this briefly,

> A queue is a particular kind of collection in which the entities in the collection are kept in order and the principal (or only) operations on the collection are the addition of entities to the rear terminal position and removal of entities from the front terminal position. This makes the queue a First-In-First-Out (FIFO) data structure. **In a FIFO data structure, the first element added to the queue will be the first one to be removed.** This is equivalent to the requirement that once an element is added, all elements that were added before have to be removed before the new element can be invoked. A queue is an example of a linear data structure.

<sup>1. If you want to know how exacly it gives strong exception guarantee, then you can start another topic, because it's very long story, and requires lots of patience to understand it properly. I would suggest you to read Exceptional C++ by Herb Sutter for this.</sup>

Comment: It might still be useful to peek at elements in the queue other than the next to be popped off.  If queues support the `size()` method, why can't they also expose iterators (or even `operator[]`) when the underlying container supports them?  Because the interface is intentionnaly minimalistic.  The only reason it doesn't support `operator[]` (or iterators) is that the standard commitee wanted a "pure" queue interface.

Comment: @Andre: I think what you said is true. But then in that case, the first question would be : why it provides `size()` and `back()` interfaces, which do not go well with the definition of queue. But then it seems that they wanted to provide more functionalities than queue supposed to have (by definition), and at the same time, they wanted to make it minimalistic.

Comment: In any case, it has to either provide `size()` or `empty()` so that you can respect the preconditions on `front()` (must ensure the queue contains at least one element).  There are many instances of the standard library that could use a few convenient overloads (such as a version for `for_each` that computes `.begin()` and `.end()` itself) for common cases.  The reason is always a combination of 1) oversight; 2) keeping interfaces consistent; and 3) keeping the standard as short as possible.  Thankfully some of these are being addressed by C++11.

Comment: @Andre: Every standard container supports `size` and `back`. Not every standard container supports `operator[]`. If they had put that into a `std::queue`, not only would it stop being a _queue_, you couldn't use a `std::list` as the storage for it anymore.

Comment: @Nicol: because unused template functions are not instantiated, you could still use `std::list` as a container, you just couldn't use `std::queue<T,std::list<T>>::operator[]`.

Answer (score 4):

It's a concept issue. In a queue, you add to the back and take from the front, not from the middle

Answer (score 3):

The reason not to include it because a queue is a data structure with enqueue and dequeue operations, not random access. `std::queue` exists to adapt an existing container into a queue interface, so it only provides the queue interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [] then use a deque with push_front and back/pop_back not a queue.

Why a double ended queue has it but not a queue doesn't make sense to me either.